# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' with strapi/webpack v5

Tags: node.js, webpack, strapi

As the title suggests, i am facing an issue of

> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

this happens after ive installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client onto my back-end, which is using Strapi v4.8.2, which also means im using webpack >= 5

things ive tried:

adding to my package.json file

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
```

adding to my src/admin/webpack.config.js file (which also leads to uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in main.bundle.js after the server is compiled and ran)

```
    config.target = 'node';
    config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false
    }
    config.target = 'node';
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "node-loader",
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.m?js/,
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false
        }
    });
```